# Win32: Displaying a Stock Icon in a Dialog Box under High DPI

Tags: user-interface, winapi, dialog, icons, dpi

I've got a dialog box where I need to display the standard Information icon. Here's my RC code:

```
ICON    "",IDC_ICON_INFORMATION,18,70,21,20
```

I process the WM_INITDIALOG message as follows:

```
HICON aIcn = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);
SendDlgItemMessage(m_hWnd, IDC_ICON_INFORMATION, STM_SETICON, (WPARAM) aIcn, 0);
```

Everything works great under 96 DPI: the static control displays a 32x32-pixel icon.

However, when I switch to higher DPI's (through right-clicking on the **Desktop**, choosing **Screen resolution**, and clicking **Make or other items larger or smaller**) the icon does not scale! Since everything else scales nicely, the icon looks visually much smaller than the neighboring text. I would expect that on 144 DPI (150%) the icon dimensions will be 48x48 pixels. I did declare my application as DPI-aware through an XML manifest.

The damnedest thing is that when I use my own custom-made icon (also coming from the RC file), everything scales perfectly. Furthermore, the `MessageBox` function called with the `MB_ICONINFORMATION` flag does display a scaled version of the icon, as well.

Given these thoughts, I assume of the following:

1. The static control with the `SS_ICON` style can display scaled versions of icons.
2. The icon resource that contains the standard Information icon has a scaled version of the icon (48x48).

What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: Looks like the `LoadIconWithScaleDown` function (available in Vista and above) can do the job. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045%28VS.85%29.aspx)() instead of LoadIcon(), and specify the cxDesired and cyDesired params with the values you get from GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON) and GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON).

Or maybe just declaring your app as DPI aware could be enough? You can try that easily by simple creating a text file making it a manifest file.
See the example in the remarks section for the [SetProcessDPIAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633543.aspx) API

Comment: Tried all this. The program is already DPI-aware through manifest. That's written in the original question.